# PSQL command does nothing

Tags: postgresql, flask, psql

Excuse my stupid question and my English
the psql command does nothing, it just freezes the Terminal/CMD,
i waited for more than 30 minutes and nothing happened.
and i can't type anything after typing psql

[picture of what i'm doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvDft.png)

Comment: It's supposed to be a shell where to enter commands. Even if there is no prompt, did you try to type any?

Comment: @B.Go
I was using Git Bash 
i will install Bash Shell and try again
thanks for commenting

Comment: everything is working fine now, I used  * SQL Shell (psql) *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SQL Shell (psql), and everything will be fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use cmd or power shell as usually, actually password typed in cmd but we cannot see